# Count days based on couple of date fields in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is a sample of what I have in my table (SQL Server):

```
patientID    DateCreated    StartOn      EndOn
---------------------------------------------------
1234         2015-09-16     2015-09-01   2015-09-30   
2345         2015-09-16     2015-09-01   2015-09-30
2346         2015-09-16     2015-09-01   2015-09-30
```

Currently, it counts the "days" to be 30. So it is really looking at days elapsed between `StartOn` and `EndOn`. I want to be able to do this counting based on `StartOn` and `DateCreated`. So, in my example the "days" should be 16, that is days elapsed from `StartOn` to `DateCreated`.

Comment: Can you show your sql query for counting 30? I suppose you just need to change your fields in your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DateDiff(Day,StartOn,DateCreated)`

Answer (score 0):

So you can go with:

```
  Select (EndOn - DateCreated +1) As "Days"
  from Tablename
  where patientID = 1234;
```